# Why validation not work for encoded password

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

In my project i add some validation for Signup form fields. While click on submit button password validation not check orignal password like `@AAAzzz123` but it check encoded password like `$2a$10$kUm6AxxH3SNSIoUtP6V7WOlFTIORTOILKDFGOP` and produce validation error message. Here down is my code.

**Entity**

```
public class User {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[^\\da-zA-Z]).{8,15}$")
    private String password;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String resiterUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
                                  BindingResult result)
    {
        
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "signup";
        }

        // Problem is here
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepo.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
}
```

**View**

```
<form th:action="@{/register}" method="post">
    
    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
        <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cg">Password</label>
        <input type="password" 
            th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('password') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}" 
            class="form-control form-control-lg"
            name="password" />
        <div id="validation" class="text-danger" th:each="e: ${#fields.errors('password')}" th:text=${e}>

        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-flex">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two phases of validation - the MVC layer and the JPA layer. If you use the same model class for both layers then you can't use the same field for two different things.

You can separate them like this, for example:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Column(name = "password")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\$2[aby]\\$.{56}$")
    private String encodedPassword

    // for form binding only
    private transient String newPassword;

}
```

```java
user.setEncodedPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getNewPassword()));
```

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej you were trying to validate that the user-entered password follows the rules of the encoded password, and then report that to the user.